# Take a screenshot of only the EditText value

Tags: button, android-edittext, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of only the EditText value not whole view of the activity and the value of the edittext is entered dynamically by users and whrn user clicked on Button, the screenshot of edittext value should be capture and save it into the device.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Context con;
    EditText etName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        declareData();

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScreenshot)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takeScreenshot();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void declareData()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        con = MainActivity.this;
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    }
    private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            //View v2 = getCurrentFocus().getRootView().findFocus();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to take an image, instead of saving the text? **Why**? A bitmap is **much more heavy** than a string! And you have to do some work to screenshot it. It doesn't seem a great idea.

Comment: I want to construct a demo program that take screenshot of edittext value and then directly share to social media like facebook or twitter. @ Hrundi

Comment: You better share the string only.

Comment: Is there any other way to take screenshot of edittext value? @HrundiV.Bakshi

Comment: The point is... do not take it. Just take the string value.

Comment: get the string value using **etName.getText().toString()** right? @HrundiV.Bakshi

Comment: Yes. That's easier, lighter, faster, ... the ideal solution.

Comment: ohk..thank u @HrundiV.Bakshi